# Create a business directory in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory, directory-listing

I am currently working on a project which involves creating a Business Directory. I have become really interesed in Ruby on Rails and I would like to know if such a thing is possible in Ruby..

I know that this may be a broad question which may not be fully suitable for StackOverflow, however there is not much information on this for Ruby.

The site would have a directory of business firms and people would be able to type in keywords of a business or business type they are looking for along with their post code and this will filter the results to show the most relevant businesses close to their address.

Example website:

http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/

If there is a way to to something like this I would be grateful if someone could give me guidance.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Example of [Search Bar to be like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol4Zo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ruby on Rails can be used pretty effectively, nothing particularly special about the concepts you mention, so it would work well enough I'd have thought. It can also be done in pretty much any other language also - Java, Python et al.

You would probably also add Javascript, Jquery and Ajax, as well as some CSS, and of course HTML, into the application to make it nice on the front end.

For the backend, you will most likely use a standard database, so a little knowledge of SQL would come in handy.

If you are going to start from scratch, including all this? Depends on your learning style. Books, online tutorials, Mentoring (e.g. http://www.railsmentors.org/), trial and error. Personally I find having an objective and then a lot of effort, and I'm up to speed.

It really depends on the person doing the learning of course. How clever, determined, experienced and effective you are. It could take you 3 weeks, or 3 years.